# Touchpad works only after waking from Suspend

Tags: release-loki, touchpad, suspend, laptop, asus

**Specs:**
(Asus Laptop)

Processor: Intel i5-6200U
Graphics: HD520 (Active), GT930M

Touchpad: Elan Touchpad

OS: elementary OS 0.4.1 64-bit (Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS)

Kernel: 4.8.0-53-generic

**Problem**

The touchpad does not work when the laptop boots up. It did not work during the (fresh) installation I did a few days ago. (I've used elementaryOS 0.4 before on this laptop but I did not encounter an issue with the touchpad.)

**Touchpad does work***

If I put my laptop to suspend, then when I wake the laptop the touchpad starts working.

**Relevant Snippets from Commands**

- dmesg | grep -i elan

> [ 12.947290] i2c-ELAN1000:00 supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
>
> [ 13.270470] input: Elan Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-9/i2c-ELAN1000:00/input/input12

- cat /proc/bus/input/devices

> I: Bus=0018 Vendor=04f3 Product=0005 Version=0000
>
> N: Name="Elan Touchpad"
>
> P: Phys=
>
> S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-9/i2c-ELAN1000:00/input/input12
>
> U: Uniq=
>
> H: Handlers=mouse0 event12
>
> B: PROP=5
>
> B: EV=b
>
> B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
>
> B: ABS=663800013000003

- xinput --list

> ⎡ Virtual core pointer id=2 [master pointer (3)]
>
> ⎜ ↳ ...
>
> ⎜ ↳ Elan Touchpad id=12 [slave pointer (2)]

If you need to see the output from any other command just post a comment.

Comment: Interesting point as during my previous install I wasn't using TLP and did not face any issue with the touchpad. However I have TLP running on my system this time around (totally forgot about it). Luckily as the touchpad issue seems resolved (at least for now) I don't want to remove it as I feel I am getting better battery-life than before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to kernel 4.10.0-28-generic fixes the issue. The touchpad works on boot itself.

Comment: That's funny it fixed your mouse issue. 4.10.0.28 screwed mine up.